# How does SLAM handle a changing environment?

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, ros-melodic, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Through SLAM, the map can be built for navigation.

But the environment usually changes.

When the environment, how does SLAM handle it?

For exmaple,

a) something is added into the environment

b) something is removed from the environment

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391357/how-does-slam-handle-a-changing-environment?/) by [wyfeng2013](https://answers.ros.org/users/88939/wyfeng2013/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2021-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are many ways to address this challenge for dynamic changes to the environment, for example multi session graph based SLAM. It also depends on what is changing in the environment, is it pedestrians walking by? Or is it furniture moving around?

Take a look at the following [paper](https://introlab.3it.usherbrooke.ca/mediawiki-introlab/images/e/eb/Labbe14-IROS.pdf)

Summary of the approach used:

> the underlying structure of the map is
> a graph with nodes and links. The
> nodes save odometry poses for each
> location in the map. The nodes also
> contain visualization information like
> laser scans, RGB images, depth images
> and visual words [17] used for loop
> closure detection. The links store
> rigid geometrical transformations
> between nodes. There are two types of
> links: neighbor and loop closure.
> Neighbor links are added between the
> current and the previous nodes with
> their odometry transformation. Loop
> closure links are added when a loop
> closure detection is found between the
> current node and one from the same or
> previous maps. Our contribution in
> this paper involves combining two
> algorithms, loop closure detection
> [16] and graph optimization [14],
> through a memory management process
> [16] that limits the number of nodes
> available from the graph for loop
> closure detection and graph
> optimization, so that they always
> satisfy online requirements.

But there are other examples of using machine learning for object detection and remove those objects while updating SLAM, take a look at this [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8996770)

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wyfeng2013](https://answers.ros.org/users/88939/wyfeng2013/) on 2021-11-23**:
The information from you give me so much help!
Thanks for you very much !